# getting RoutingError after upgrade to Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an application on Heroku, and after I update to Rails 4.1.0 I'm seeing these `RoutingError`s exception:

```
Started GET "/assets/Elusive-Icons-5997c1a6679785a96defc4f57a3f2ff5.svg" for 177.16.216.169 at 2014-04-12 21:56:41 +0000
2014-04-12T21:56:41.397071+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-04-12T21:56:41.397071+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/Elusive-Icons-5997c1a6679785a96defc4f57a3f2ff5.svg"):
```

I installed rails_12factor and tried to put `config.serve_static_assets = true` on `applicationl.rb` but no effect. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried recompiling your production assets after you upgraded?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you should input this into your cmd: `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` -- this, coupled with deploying to Heroku, should solve the issue

Comment: I have `public/assets` on my gitignore. should I remove this line? EDIT: removed the line, but no difference